# 2.8: How to assign a Procedural "wood" texture(for example) i just made to a material

Tags: texturing

Hope its not a too stupid question,but i have a problem.

I just created a simple procedural wood texture,and wanted to apply it to a Material i just made.
I really dont know how (i use to apply image texture in node editor,but with procedural is my first time trying)

I saw a tutorial made on 2.7 i guess,and the moment the guy create a material,then creates the procedural texture,the procedural is showed on the material and on the render right away.On my 2.8,this doesnt happen

I can see the named "texture.002" in this menu list,but not elsewhere.

..My question is.Where do the texture i make on this menu goes,and how to apply it to a material?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "created a procedural wood texture? Is it a node group? In that case, plug the output of the texture into the color input for your shader.

Comment: Im sorry.i should had say.Im adding a pic to the post

Comment: Where is your shader graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhh... you raise an excellent point, actually.

The short answer is:

1. Ensure the Viewport Shading type in the top right is set to Look Dev or Rendered, not Solid.
2. In the Shading workspace or any Shader Editor, edit your Material, setting the Base Colour type to use a Wave Texture Node. There is no 'Wood'. It's kinda weird.

So... creating that Wood Texture on the right-side Textures context doesn't really do anything - it's showing your Brush and Brush Mask textures. Procedural textures aren't really 'stored' how you may expect.

The Nodes you *would* use to get the same procedural effects have completely inconsistent names with the list of texture types on that Texture tab.
I haven't looked into this, but there's probably a developer discussion about sorting this all out, because until I tried answering your question I hadn't really realised what an utter mess that all is.

Here's a shader editor showing all the Texture node types available... beside the list of texture names on that tab. I'm slightly baffled, to be honest.

[image: Image showing inconsistency between Texture panel and Texture Nodes]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!So that context texture menu remains a non fully working feature lets say..

Comment: Yeah, I think that's fair. Although, it was 'fully working' in the past, I think, it's just that it used to be much more integral to the texturing process when Blender Internal was the main renderer, and now it's just slightly different what it's used for, so it makes less sense. I'm sure they'll streamline it and tidy up the inconsistencies as they gradually overhaul things.